# TIFF File invalid or unsupported after gaussin filter in scikit-image library

Tags: python, image-processing, save, filtering, scikit-image

I have a [RGB *.TIFF image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Vt3k6ChHIseXhpX1BTbTRjQU0/view) imported with [scikit-image library](http://scikit-image.org/). I wish to apply the *Gaussian filter* and save a TIFF file again.

When i open this file with a viewer software (es: IrfanView) i get a message about the file is invalid or unsupported as TIFF file. Inside Python i can plot without problem the array and see the effect of the filter.

```
from skimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from skimage import filters
from skimage import img_as_float
from skimage import exposure
from PIL import Image
import os

myimage = '~prova2.tiff'
im = io.imread(myimage)

array([[[11368, 10479,  7155],
        [11632,  9333,  7155],
        [11893, 10107,  7574],
        ..., 
        ...,
        ..., 
        [15262, 13399, 13285],
        [15782, 13878, 13186],
        [15782, 13666, 13087]]], dtype=uint16)

im.dtype
dtype('uint16')
im.shape
(4024L, 6024L, 3L)
```

on this image i apply a gaussian filter implemented in skimage

```
im_gaussian = gaussian_filter(im, sigma=5, multichannel=True)
array([[[ 0.17088626,  0.16434972,  0.1129538 ],
        [ 0.17117972,  0.16493729,  0.11318613],
        [ 0.17150206,  0.16562064,  0.11345394],
        ..., 
        ...,
        ..., 
        [ 0.22970595,  0.21051914,  0.19862151],
        [ 0.22982556,  0.21036883,  0.19824348],
        [ 0.23003602,  0.21031404,  0.19787011]]])

io.imsave("~prova2_gaussin.tiff", im_gaussian)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the test image so that I can try and replicate this on my system?

Comment: Perhaps you need the tiff plugin from PIL: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html

Comment: @richizy also after installed tifffile i have the same problem

Comment: I have had this problem before. If possible, try changing the data type of your output image.